# ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar el resultado de la funcion mcrypt_get_block_size en php 7.2 ya que está obsoleta?

Tags: php, php7, encriptación

Esta es la función exacta que necesito reemplazar

```
$block = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'cbc');
```

Comment: Aún que estaría bien tener más contexto y saber exactamente qué estás haciendo. Entiendo que lo que buscas es `openssl_cipher_iv_length` https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.openssl-cipher-iv-length

Comment: espero te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/mcrypt-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative

Answer (score 0):

Luego de buscar y leer acerca del tema, comento todo por si alguien necesita solucionar.

Tengo Laragon instalado con php 7.2.8, una integración con un sistema de pagos, me obliga a usar la librería "mcrypt" para encriptar la firma, razón por la cual, debí incluir la librería en mi sistema.

Lo que hice fue lo siguiente

1-Descargué la la última versión de dll de la librería.

```
    https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt/1.0.3/windows
```

2-Descomprimí y coloqué el dll en la carpeta de extensiones ../php/ext/

3-Agregué 2 líneas a mi php.ini

```
    extension=imap
    extension=mcrypt
```

reinicié el servidor y funcionó.